# k8s pod can only access the host it is on

Tags: kubernetes

***In short, the pod can only access the host it is on.***

I have a k8s-1.15 cluster with 3 nodes and Calico plugin:

- master.test.local (192.168.1.137)
- node1.test.local (192.168.1.138)
- node2.test.local (192.168.1.139)

There are 2 pods, pod-1 running on master(1.137), and pod-2 running on node1(1.138), when I ping 192.168.1.138 from pod-1(running on 1.137), I got:

```sh
[~pod-1] # ping 192.168.1.138
PING 192.168.1.138 (192.168.1.138): 56 data bytes
```

but if I ping the 1.137 from pod-1(running on 1.137), it succeeded:

```sh
[~pod-1] # ping 192.168.1.137
PING 192.168.1.137 (192.168.1.137): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.137: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.137: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
```

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered in [Issue #2543](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2543#issuecomment-484274834)

> this looks to be working as expected, since your network policy doesn't have any egress rules.
>
> If you want to deny egress from pod A, you can add the following section to the NetworkPolicy:
>
> ```
> types:
> - Ingress
> - Egress
> ```
>
> This will tell the policy to apply to both ingress and egress traffic, and all egress from pod A will be denied unless you specify egress rules.
>
> Alternatively, you can create an ingress policy which selects pod B in order to prevent pod A from accessing it.

You can use `calicoctl profile` to edit the default policy that forbids inbound traffic

```sh
calico profile {{ profile_name }} rule add inbound allow from <ip>
```